# Ionic Creator not exporting tabs-controller

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've started a project with Ionic Creator, but it looks like it's really a half-baked product. For starters it made some duplicate declarations which have to be manually removed. But the real problem is that it doesn't seem to export all the essential components of the generated template.

Here is the project, feel free looking at it:
https://creator.ionic.io/share/aecc1ca8b22f

It's a tab-based Ionic 3.x project. When I export it as zip, the `TabsControllerPage` component in the `pages/tabs-controller` directory is missing.

So... where is it? Or should I rebuild it manually? (Then what is the point of Creator?)

Comment: You need to report them: https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=633568

Comment: I already did. I just wonder if it's a bug or a feature.